# Invoke function at derived class when file changed

Tags: c#, inheritance, filesystemwatcher

I have:

```
protected FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
public A()
{
   ...
    watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
}
protected virtual void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

I need when change occur at the file that would Invoke fonction at the derived class, I have tried like:

```
public B():A
{
   watcher.Changed +=OnChangedDerived;
}


void OnChangedDerived(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  //do more stuff
}
```

But it doesn't invoke the function at the derived class

Comment: Then probably remove the event registration from `A`

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code in class B is not correct.

it should be:

```
 watcher.Changed +=OnChangedDerived;
```

One more thing from OOP perspective, you have a virtual method in your base class.  You can just override it in the derived class if you want to customize the event handling in the derived class.   You do not need to subscribe it again.

**Code Sample:**

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    protected FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    public BaseClass()
    {
       ...
        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
    }

    protected virtual void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
      //do stuff
    }

}


public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
       protected override void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
       {
            //// your custom handling in the derived class.
       }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: Ok.  also, instead of subscribing in the derived class, you can override the virtual method in your base class.